# Django - logout view customisation fail

Tags: python, django, url, view, logout

### Although the original question is cleared out, there's a new related question which is quite interesting: (please let me know if my theory is remotely correct...)

Please checkout my urlpatterns below:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from boutique.models import Category
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [

    # to customise login view
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(extra_context = {'categories': Category.objects.get_categories_with_item()})),
    # path('login/', views.NewLoginView.as_view()),

    # to customise default logout view
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'categories': Category.objects.get_categories_with_item()}),

    # include django authentication urls
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

As you probably noticed that there are two different ways to pass in `extra_context`, the interesting thing is: The method used on `LogoutView` can not be used on `LoginView`!! However, The method used on `LoginView` does work on `LogoutView`.

I think the possible explanation and yet to be confirmed by you lot is that they inherit different views:

`LoginView`:

```py
class LoginView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, FormView):
    """
    Display the login form and handle the login action.
    """
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    authentication_form = None
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = False
    extra_context = None

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        context.update({
            self.redirect_field_name: self.get_redirect_url(),
            'site': current_site,
            'site_name': current_site.name,
            **(self.extra_context or {})
        })
        return context
```

`LogoutView`:

```py
class LogoutView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, TemplateView):
    """
    Log out the user and display the 'You are logged out' message.
    """
    next_page = None
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'registration/logged_out.html'
    extra_context = None

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        context.update({
            'site': current_site,
            'site_name': current_site.name,
            'title': _('Logged out'),
            **(self.extra_context or {})
        })
        return context
```

I think the reason that `LoginView` has to pass the `extra_context` as a positional argument into `.as_view()` is that it doesn't inherit from `TemplateView`:

```py
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):
    """
    Render a template. Pass keyword arguments from the URLconf to the context.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

which has a `get` method to get context data... if i'm not mistaken.

## ***Could anyone confirm this?***

I'm quite new to python and django framework. Thanks a lot!!!

---

## The Original question has been answered

Please checkout the answers in the comments session --

---

I'm fairly new to Django and in order to pass in more context to logout view I tried 2 methods to customise the logout view:

### Method 1:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from boutique.models import Category

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'categories': Category.objects.all()}),

    # I also tried this:
    # path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view({'categories': Category.objects.all()}),


    # I also tried this: 
    # path('logout-customised-url/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'categories': Category.objects.all()}),
    # This is working tho it wouldn't be automatically redirect to this path when logged out
```

### Method 2:

```py
    ...
    path('logout/', views.NewLogoutView.as_view()),
    # NewLogoutView code below:
```

views.py

```py
from boutique.models import Category
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView


class NewLogoutView(LogoutView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

---

Still not working, and the outcome is exactly the same: if a customised url is in use such as 'logged-out/' instead of 'logout/', and you type out the url, it renders the correct page with the extra context. However, wouldn't *go to* the page when users log out normally...

Is there any workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! The problem was in the order of my urlpatterns, originally it was like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [

    # include django authentication urls
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    # to customise default logout view
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'categories': Category.objects.get_categories_with_item()}),
```

Based on [official doc: Authentication Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), `django.contrib.auth.urls` includes many url patterns, such as:

```py
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

Therefore, they take precedence if they were declared before the customised. So:

```py
urlpatterns = [

    # to customise default logout view
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'categories': Category.objects.get_categories_with_item()}),


    # include django authentication urls
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

To swap the order, it works.

---

To the roockies like me:
*Method 1* does work. Just pass in the additional context/argument like it states in the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) after the view.

Also, I checked `django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView`:

```py
class LogoutView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, TemplateView):
    """
    Log out the user and display the 'You are logged out' message.
    """
    next_page = None
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'registration/logged_out.html'
    extra_context = None
    ...
```

The `extra_context` is set to `None` for you to add extra context. Easy to customise if were to subclass it or simply pass in a positional argument into `.as_view()` -- which means:

```py
urlpatterns = [

    # to customise login view
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(extra_context = {'categories': Category.objects.get_categories_with_item()})),

]

`Loginview` has the same the same convenient settings...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `extra_context` in your `urls.py` inorder to send extra context to logout view. read more about [passing extra context to a view from in url definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions).

```
path(
    'logout/',
    auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),
    {'extra_context':{'categories': Category.objects.all()}}
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but in [the official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) it doesn't say it needs `extra_context` as the key to the additional context... `path('blog/<int:year>/', views.year_archive, {'foo': 'bar'}),` Did I miss anything? or this only applies to function based view?

Comment: `extra_context` is not from that doc, page I found it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glyphack. I've figured it out, it's actually the order in which the url patterns are presented. And I've tried your way adding `{'extra_context':{'categories': Category.objects.all()}` at the end, however, it didn't work. Passing `{'categories': Category.objects.all()}` worked. I gather you don't need to set a key to the extra context. Django will recognise it itself.